# pyCharm installed via terminal but cannot find in Applications

Tags: pycharm

I've downloaded pyCharm from jetbrains website. Then I've extracted that downloaded file and via terminal I ran this command to install pycharm,

```
./pycharm.sh
```

Is stopped with the mention `Installation completed` so I activated the pycharm. But later I searched on Applications but could not find pycharm.  Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `./pycharm.sh`, did it ask you whether you wanted to create a launcher entry? If it didn't or you didn't select it, run it again and create a launcher entry by going to Tools menu and selecting Create Launcher Entry. Maybe a restart of the system might help too.

Comment: It won't create  the launcher by default, you have to tell it to do that as you indicatedl

Comment: Thank you @Ankur22 it works for me by using Tool menu...